# javascripts and drop-downs work in development and production modes but both fail when deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

I'm deploying a rails app to Heroku, and the process runs smoothly but on running the app in a browser, javascripts and drop-downs do not work.
I thought the Turbolinks might be the problem but after i fixed it locally, it doesn't seem to reflect in Heroku.

i have tried restarting the app server on Heroku using

```
'heroku restart'
```

i tried precompiling the assets in development mode before deploying using

```
'heroku run rake assets:precompile -a rhino-base'
```

i tried inspecting elements using chrome>inspect>console but i only see 1 error yet ALL the js scripts don't work.

here is my GEM FILE

```
'source 'https://rubygems.org'
 git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.4.5'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1', '>= 5.2.1.1'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development do
  # Use mysql as the database for Active Record
  gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
end

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 4.1.18'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'duktape'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
    # Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
    ##################################################
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    gem 'jquery-slimscroll-rails','~> 1.0','>= 1.0.9'
    gem 'jquery-migrate-rails', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.1'
##################################################
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
 gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]'
```

heres my application.js FILE '

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require_tree .
//= require turbolinks'
```

here is my production.rb FILE

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
    # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "rhinoBaseSite_#{Rails.env}"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

I expected that since everything works in development and production, it should also work on deployment.

Comment: When you load the site from heroku servers, is the application.js file loaded at all? What does the browser's network inspector and resource inspector say? Any output in the browser console? Check these guides https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ if you need help on using the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

so anyone else with this problem, here is what worked for me. Not all javascript files play nice when compiled in a single space. Compile them separately.
in your
`config/initializers/assets.rb` file have this line for the specific script you would love to compile in a separate file 
`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( path-to-file-in-javascripts-folder/file-name.js  path-to-file-in-stylesheet-folder/file-name.scss)` 
for example 
`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js )`
then update your application.js and remove 
`//= require tree`
then update your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file and add the precompile asset path adding the `/assets` before the location. Like this
`<%= javascript_include_tag '/assets/plugins/datatables/export/pdfmake.min' %>`
now put all the files you had precompiled inside of the public/assets folder. then push to heroku.